# Github Restful API commit by sha

Tags: c#, github

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction to calling github api v3 to get commit details by sha.  I'm getting a consistent message "Not found

```
{
message: "Not Found"
}
```

the call I am making is:

https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{reponame}/{sha}

do I need a key or security token to complete this call?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that this is the URL you need:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo name}/git/commits/{sha}
```

Example:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/git/commits/3934bc47e17620eb27876e9079ebe360611f8693
```

Comment: @guillaumepotier I just picked it from the github front page :P